# Error when trying to access WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a very simple service created in a Class Library type project called fn34-webservice.

Here's the interface and the class for the service(they are in separate files):

```
namespace fn34_webservice
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEstoqueWS
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ItemEstoque GetQuantidade(string codigo);
    }
}

namespace fn34_webservice
{
    public class EstoqueWS : IEstoqueWS
    {
        private Dictionary<string, ItemEstoque> repositorio = new Dictionary<string, ItemEstoque>();

        public EstoqueWS()
        {
            repositorio.Add("SOA", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "SOA", Quantidade = 5 });
            repositorio.Add("TDD", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "TDD", Quantidade = 1 });
            repositorio.Add("RES", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "RES", Quantidade = 2 });
            repositorio.Add("LOG", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "LOG", Quantidade = 4 });
            repositorio.Add("WEB", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "WEB", Quantidade = 1 });
            repositorio.Add("ARQ", new ItemEstoque() { Codigo = "ARQ", Quantidade = 2 });
        }

        public ItemEstoque GetQuantidade(string codigo)
        {
            return repositorio[codigo];
        }
    }
}
```

So, I create this simple Empty Web Site to host the server and test it locally. I added a reference to my project fn34-webservice and in the web.config of the website added this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment >
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="./WsHost/fn34-webservice.svc"
         service="fn34-webservice.fn34-webservice"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I run it and try to access the url `http://localhost:49487/WsHost/fn34-webservice.svc` I got the following error:

```
The type 'fn34-webservice.fn34-webservice', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

My guess is that it's probably something dumb in my web.config file, but I can't manage to find it out.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In your config you have `fn34-webservice.fn34-webservice`, but in your code the namespace and class name use an underscore (_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong fully qualified name for your service.

In your config file you have `fn34-webservice.fn34-webservice`.  However, your web service is actually named `EstoqueWS` and the namespace is `fn34_webservice` (note the `_`).

Try updating your config file to use the fully qualified name `fn34_webservice.EstoqueWS`, like this:

```
<serviceActivations>
  <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
        relativeAddress="./WsHost/fn34-webservice.svc"
        service="fn34_webservice.EstoqueWS"/>
</serviceActivations>
```